# cool-retro-term doesn't understand the {} symbols

Tags: command-line, emacs

I installed cool-retro-term. It works fine except for one thing: when I try any text editor (vi, emacs, etc), I cannot write the symbols {}.
When I used another terminal, I do not have the problem (that's why I think it's a terminal issue and not an OS or editor issue).
I work mostly in C descendant languages (javascript, java, go, etc), so the use of these symbols is very important.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does its default font have those symbols?  Can you change the font?

Comment: what does "can't write the symbols" mean? Do you get an empty space? cursor doesn't move? other symbols? What keyboard layout?

Comment: cursor jumps two lines up, and don't print the symbol